# In .NET - If 'Using' statement raises an Exception , what is the action to be performed?

Tags: .net, exception, dispose, using

1. Call the Dispose()
2. Don't Call the Dispose()
3. Only Raise the Exception
4. Raise the Exception , and also call the Dispose()

What is the correct answer ?

Comment: I do attend an interview in .NET , I wanted to know the correct answer for this quest

Comment: What do you mean by "what do I need to do"? Do you mean "what does the  `using` statement do for me?"

Comment: what have you read so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx)?

> The C# "using" statement results in a call to Dispose(). This is the
>   same as Close(), which may throw exceptions when a network error
>   occurs. Because the call to Dispose() happens implicitly at the
>   closing brace of the "using" block, this source of exceptions is
>   likely to go unnoticed both by people writing the code and reading the
>   code. This represents a potential source of application errors.

as it says "the call to Dispose() happens implicitly" so i hope that solves the problem